# Speeding Monte Carlo in matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, profile, profiler, montecarlo

I'm trying to speed up the following Monte Carlo simulation in matlab:

http://pastebin.com/nS0K7XXa

and this is the full result of the matlab profiler

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVOtT.png

I am pretty new at using matlab, but I spent a good deal of time already on this and I think I'm missing something somewhere, because I have the feeling that this should run much faster.

I'm concerned about the lines the profiler show in red of course... lets start with these ones:

```
time  calls      line           code
37.59 19932184   54             radselec = fix(rand(1)*nr) + 1; 
 4.54 19932184   55             nm = nm - 1; 
45.35 19932184   56             Rad2(radselec) = Rad2(radselec) + 1;
```

I have a very large vector (Rad2) which holds positive integer values, initially they are all zero but as the simulation progresses it fills up.

line 54 picks a random element of that vector, everytime I add a value to that vector I also add a value to the variable nr, so basically nr is `numel(nr)` and `fix(rand(1)*nr)+1` will pick a random number between 1 and nr.

Question 1: Is there a better way of doing this? rand(1) alone seems to take a long time, as you can see from line 26:

```
31.50 20540616   26     r = rand(1);
```

Question 2: line 56 also called my attention... once I have a value for radselec, I need to add +1 to the value of Rad2(radselec).

Now I thought that doing `Rad2(radselec) = Rad2(radselec) + 1;` was just as fast as doing `nm = nm - 1` or +1 for that matter... but the profiler shows that adding +1 to an element of a vector is 10 times slower.

Question 3:

```
 31.50 20540616   26     r = rand(1); 
                  27     
 22.72 20540616   28     if r > R1/Rt 
  3.39 20220062   29         reacselec = 2; 
 10.80 20220062   30         if r > (R1+R2)/Rt
```

rand(1) seems to be slow as it is... by definition I need that random number between 0 and 1. So I can't think of another way of speeding that line up.

Now... How come line 28 is 2 times slower than line 30 ??? I mean... they are practically the same line with the same calculation... if anything line 30 should be slightle slower for having R1+R2 in the numerator, instead of just R1.

What's happening there?

And finally,

```
 24.26 20540616   79  end
```

why is that end statement chugging so many time? How can fix that?

Thank you for your time, and sorry if this questions are too basic. I just started programming a few months ago, and I do not have a computer science background. I'm thinking on taking some courses, but that's not a priority.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: A lot of what you're seeing is function call overhead. This is Matlab, can you not vectorize the random number generation, i.e., allocate random variates in large chunks? I realize that that is might be challenging in some Monte-Carlo codes order to retain repeatability, etc. If you want even faster, compile the [SIMD-oriented Fast Mersenne Twister](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/SFMT/index.html) as a `mex` function. And I think the `end` is just the cost of the `while` loop condition.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to avoid having to learn how to use the mex compiler, but I guess I'm gonna have to in the long run anyway. I will try allocating all the randoms in a huge vector and see if that does it. Also, just to be sure, no way of improving that thing with the last `end`, correct?